# NPM scoped packages for private registry: Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: npm, nexus, npm-install

We are using an npm proxy repository to get packages from public npm registry and
we are using an npm hosted repository to publish packages in our vpn.

I want to install packages from proxy and my private repository in my application.

We are using Nexus repository manager.

here is my npmrc:

```
init.author.name=Name
init.author.email=you@example.com
email=you@example.com
always-auth=true
_auth=authtoken
@myco:_auth=authtoken
registry=npmproxyurl
@myco:registry=npmhostedurl
strict-ssl=false
ca=null
@myco:always-auth=true
```

I am able to publish to hosted but unable to install from it.
I keep getting this error on install

```
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: This request requires auth credentials. Run `npm login` and repeat the request.
```

I ran npm login, but entering credentials doesn't work for hosted.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you using Nexus Repository Manager 2 or 3?

Comment: When you say "entering credentials doesn't work" what does that mean?  What are you seeing?

Comment: the problem was with Nexus configuration. This npmrc config is working for me nw.

Comment: @AkankshaGaur, can you please post the correct configuration as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

you miss the registry URI on the configuration.